# Passing the variable value between servers in PHP

Tags: php

I have 2 php file:

1. `serwer1.pl/file1.php`:

   ```
   $code = ($_GET['code']);
   $myfile = fopen("main.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
   fwrite($myfile, $code);
   fclose($myfile);
   echo $code;
   ```
2. `serwer2.pl/file2.php`:

   ```
   $code = "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";
   echo  ($code);
   ```

How can I send a CODE variable from server2 (file2) to server1 (file1)?

Comment: `$code = file_get_contents('https://serwer2.pl/file2.php');`

Comment: I can not do this, I have to send it via $ _GET ['code']

Answer (score 2):

Use Curl,

Add this code to your server 2 
Docs : http://php.net/manual/fr/function.curl-exec.php

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://yourdnsserver1/?code=yourcode");

curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```